# Can't install package with apt ansible module, but can from shell

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-16.04, apt

When I run from command line it works:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3.9
```

When I run with ansible it throws error:

```sh
ansible edge -m apt -a 'name=python3.9' -b -i vagrant-inventory.yaml
```

```sh
fatal: [edge]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: No package matching 'python3.9' is available
```

Ubuntu xenial, python executable python3.5.

I don't know where to dig, maybe it is some well known issue, or I should dig deeper to find my mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

@Belenot I think your ansible is running with a diffrent python version that's why the install is not working to verify this you need to type :

```
ansible --version | grep "python version"
```

if it is the case then you need to re-install ansible using pip3 :

```
pip3 install ansible
```

to overcome this compatibility issue.